# how to make full path for url in python?

Tags: python

I am little bit confused about creating full url.
I have such code :

```
    def flats(self):
        return [JsonFlatPage(property_data = flat, url = flat['propertyUrl']) 
                for flat in self.data['properties']]
```

in `flat['propertyUrl']` I have `'/properties/75599853'`, but I need to get like this one:

```
'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/75599853#/'
```

with full path and # at the end.
I know that I should make constant URI in settings file, but then how I can convert it? Should I use f-strings?

Comment: Does `flat['url']` contain domain name ?

Comment: No, only /properties/75599853

Comment: If domain is static, then u can put it in a variable like `domain_name = 'https://...'` then `url=domain_name+flat['propertyUrl']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since the base url `https://www.rightmove.co.uk/` is fixed, you can do something like below to get what you need:

```
def flats(self):
        baseUrl = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/'
        return [JsonFlatPage(property_data = flat, url = baseUrl + flat['propertyUrl'] + "#/") 
                for flat in self.data['properties']]
```

You can also use `f-strings` as you mentioned as:

```
def flats(self):
        baseUrl = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/'
        return [JsonFlatPage(property_data = flat, url = f"{baseUrl}{flat['propertyUrl']}#/") 
                for flat in self.data['properties']]
```

Comment: But if I want to make domain as attribute class and put as well in settings.py?

Comment: you can use that to update the `baseUrl` at runtime if that is present in some other dictionary.